# arreglo con matrices

Tags: java, matriz

necesito hacer que el los datos de la columna 7 (saldo total) se pasen al siguiente renglón (si es posible por ciclos for), pero ahora en la columna 1 y asi dependiendo de la cantidad de periodos que se pagará, la columna 0 es donde va el periodo, por cierto los valores que se ingresan por teclado son

```
1- periodos de pago (en meses)
2- saldo del préstamo
3- iss
4- amortización
```

y lo que debe mostrar en salida, son lo add.columna del código
un ejemplo de lo que quiero que haga es:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 
9-10-11-12-13-14-
```

que utilize el ultimo dato de la columna en este caso 9 y inicie otro renglon con ese como valor principal y haga las mismas operaciones que que hizo con el primer renglon, las operaciones hechas estan en el codigo.

```
nP -> es el numero de periodos (meses)
```

```
        modelo.addColumn("periodo");


        modelo.addColumn("saldo");


        modelo.addColumn("ISS");  // se calcula


        modelo.addColumn("amortizacion");  // 3


        modelo.addColumn("saldo Iintereses"); // se calcula


        modelo.addColumn("pago total (saldo intereses + amortizacion) "); // se calcula


        modelo.addColumn("saldo final"); // se calcula


        Object fila[] = new Object[7];
        

        
        //Iss
        double interes = Double.parseDouble(txtIss.getText()) / 100;
        // operacion de pago total
        double paTo = Double.parseDouble(txtamortizacion.getText()) + interes;

        //llenar tabla  
        lista[i][0] = nP;
        lista[i][1] = txtprestamo.getText();
        lista[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(txtprestamo.getText()) * interes; //calcula el ISS (intereses sobre saldo) 
        lista[i][3] = txtamortizacion.getText();
        lista[i][4] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(txtprestamo.getText()) + interes);// calcula el saldo intereses
        lista[i][5] = paTo;
        lista[i][6] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(txtprestamo.getText()) - paTo);

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                fila[k] = lista[j][k];
```

Comment: por favor me dirian como se hace?

Comment: sabes lo que hace el codigo que pusiste en el post?

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema que estás teniendo? Lee [ask].

Comment: el codigo llena una tabla con los datos de plazo, saldo, iss, amortizacion, pago total y saldo final, y lo que quiero hacer es que dependiendo del periodo (por meses) tome el saldo final del periodo uno y lo pase como saldo, pero e el siguiente renglon y haga otra vez todo el proceso de las operaciones y asi sucesivamente dependiendo del numero de meses

Comment: un ejemplo de lo que quiero que haga es:   123456789 -> 91011121314 <- que utilize el ultimo dato de la columna en este caso 9 y inicie otro renglon con ese como valor principal y haga las mismas operaciones que que hizo con el primer renglon,